# Maven плагин для eclipse не настраивается

Tags: eclipse, исключения, maven, build

Что только не делал. Плагин мавена в эклипсе отказывается работать. 
Создаю простой мавен-проект с "Хелоу ворлд" и сразу же появляется предупреждение. Его (предупреждение) ,в принципе убрать можно ,и он ,как бы не мешает. Второй проект я сделал простым и в него уже конвертировал МАВЕН. Но ни в первом ни во втором случае при нажатии run as install ничего не собирается. Выкидывается простынь :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building qqqq 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ qqqq ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Pavel_Butkevich\New f\qqqq\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ qqqq ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Pavel_Butkevich\New f\qqqq\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.214 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-30T10:29:44+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project qqqq: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/d...ilureException
```

на сайте по этой ошибке написана какая-то ересь(((( где как найти, как исправить, ничего(
документации к плагину для эклипс тоже найти не могу. Может кто подскажет где он лежит?

Это простыня при работе с проектом в который конвертирован мавен.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ref333 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ref333 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Pavel_Butkevich\New f\rty\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ ref333 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Pavel_Butkevich\New f\rty\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.180 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-30T10:33:42+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project ref333: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/d...ilureException
```

помогите пожалуста из-за этого сдвинуться с места немогу. Хоть пробуй теперь ИДЕЮ устанавливать(((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...ng-on-a-jre-ra

убрать предупреждение  - я пользуюсь вот этим вариантом:
https://ninadgawad.wordpress.com/201...ment-j2se-1-5/

Вот эта фраза: 
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
В какого перепугу?

Но в этом и есть загадка. В preferences проверил Installed JREs. делаю edit пути и действительно он зараза ссылается на папку JRE, а не JDK!!!!! Заменил, все стало работать. Целый день вчера убил Спасибо большое ВСЕМ!!!!!